# How to simplify this query for Oracle DB?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
OrderA
-------
userId
orderDate
amount

OrderB
------
userId
orderDate

sample data:

OrderA
1  01/01/2018 100
1  02/01/2018 101
1  03/01/2018 102

OrderB
1  01/01/2018 
1  01/10/2018 
1  03/01/2018
```

I have two order tables, OrderA and OrderB. I would like to write a query which sums user's order amounts for OrderA orders, but only includes OrderA entries if the same user placed an OrderB in the same month.

For this sample data, the query should give `202`.

This query works, but the `distinct` is slow.

```
SELECT userId, SUM (a.amount) 
FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT a.userId,
                            a.amount
            FROM            OrderA a
            INNER JOIN      OrderB b  
            ON              EXTRACT(month from a.orderDate) = EXTRACT(month from b.orderDate) AND
                            EXTRACT(year from a.orderDate) = EXTRACT(year from b.orderDate) AND
                            a.userId = b.userId
    )
GROUP BY userId
```

This query does not work, it gives `301`

```
SELECT          userId, SUM (a.amount) 
FROM            OrderA a
INNER JOIN      OrderB b  
ON              EXTRACT(month from a.orderDate) = EXTRACT(month from b.orderDate) AND
                EXTRACT(year from a.orderDate) = EXTRACT(year from b.orderDate) AND
                a.userId = b.userId    
GROUP BY userId
```

any suggestions? I feel like there is a better way to implement this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT userId, SUM (a.amount) 
FROM (
            SELECT a.userId, a.amount
              FROM OrderA a
             INNER JOIN OrderB b  
            ON              EXTRACT(month from a.orderDate) = EXTRACT(month from b.orderDate) AND
                            EXTRACT(year from a.orderDate) = EXTRACT(year from b.orderDate) AND
                            a.userId = b.userId
             GROUP BY a.userId, a.amount
    )
GROUP BY userId;
```

might be faster with the same logic without distinct.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT a.userId, SUM(a.amount) 
FROM OrderA a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM OrderB b  
              WHERE TO_CHAR(a.orderDate, 'YYYY-MM') = TO_CHAR(b.orderDate, 'YYYY-MM') AND
                    a.userId = b.userId   
            ) 
GROUP BY a.userId;
```

For performance, you want an index on `OrderB(userId, orderDate)`.

Comment: yep, that works. i don't think it's much faster. but, to me, it's a more intuitive implementation

Comment: Maybe not much faster, but at least it is correct. That must be worth something. ;)